# How to show Euro Currency code in SSRS reporting

Tags: reporting-services

In my Database the value stored in CurrencyCode is `1802.51`.

I want to show CurrencyCode for 'EUR' like €1.802,51 in an SSRS Report using the Switch condition, but this is not working:

```
Fields!CurrencyCode.Value = "EUR","'€'0.00;('€'0.00)"
```

Comment: If you only ever want to show the euro symbol, set the number format to '€'0.00;('€'0.00) and it'll work.

Comment: You say the CurrencyCode value = 1802.51.. then you also say you use a switch to determine if the value = "EUR"..  it's never going to be.. just go =format(Fields!CurrencyCode.Value,,"'€'0.00;('€'0.00)")

Comment: Fields!CurrencyCode.Value = "EUR","'€'0.00;('€'0.00)" this statement show output as €1802.51 but I want output as  €1.802,51